# Google PageSpeed not happy with Imagify

Tags: wordpress, image, compression, pagespeed

I optimised all my images in WP with the Plugin "Imagify" (in "Aggressive" mode). Still Google PageSpeed tells me I've to optimise many of my images. How come?

Plz help me, thx, LXT

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a little bit late, but for someone maybe it will also help. You can also try https://wordpress.org/plugins/cheetaho-image-optimizer/ but if you still get the same warnings from Google PageSpeed maybe you are using a bigger image than the image container is. For example, your image container is 200x200, but you try to use bigger (bigger than 200px).
One more idea can be CDN. Maybe your images are cached in CDN and optimized images can not be served at that moment :)

Answer (score -1):

For image optimazation, use can try other resources too.

https://tinypng.com/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/ (Wordpress Plugin)

I hope it work for you and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please use WP Fastest Cache plugin .
it is very good plugin to optimize the image. This plugin have all the featured which is your required in the website speed.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/